# How do I change the php max_execution_time in the wordpress docker image?

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I have been trying to change the max_execution_time value that wordpress sees for hours, with no luck. I am using the wordpress:5.5.0-php7.4-fpm-alpine docker image, along with the nginx:1.15.12-alpine image, which reverse proxies to wordpress.

Here is a list of the things I can remember trying so far:

wp-config.php:

```
ini_set('max_execution_time', 300);
```

```
set_time_limit(300);
```

nginx.conf:

```
fastcgi_param PHP_VALUE max_execution_time=300;
```

.htaccess

```
php_value max_execution_time 300
```

```
max_execution 300
```

.user.ini (in wordpress directory)

```
max_execution_time = 300
```

---

If I create a config.php which prints `phpinfo()`, `max_execution_time` updates when I change the .user.ini file or the PHP_VALUE in the nginx config.

However, the "max execution time" reported by wordpress (via woocommerce status page) refuses to change from 120. I cannot find any configuration that says 120 seconds, so I am completely boggled by this.

Comment: Do not forget to restart the webservice when changing directives. .htaccess will work only for apache.

Comment: Thanks @MarkusZeller, I tried .htaccess as a "throw everything at the wall" move.

Comment: I solved it. The "Exploit Scanner" plugin apparently changed the value for the whole application. I disabled that and the problem went away. That was crazy!